# stat file from DIR *

Tags: c, linux

I have written a function which accepts `DIR *` as argument and lists files inside that (with `readdir` function)

In addition, I just want to be able to `stat` files returned by `readdir`. It is not clear where `DIR *` is pointing to, so is there a way to get full path of directory from `DIR *` or is there any other way that I can `stat` files with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dirfd()`, as many other answers, and then for each entry read with `readdir()` call function `fstatat()`:

```
int fstatat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, struct stat *buf, int flags);
```

I think this relatively obscure function does just what you need.

Alternatively you could call `openat()` passing in the fd of the directory and the pathname read from the directory. Then do a `fstat()` to get the file stats.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but you should be able to use `dirfd()` to get the file descriptor corresponding to the `DIR *`, and using that you can call `fchdir()` to change into that directory.

Then the names returned by `readdir()` become local to your current dir, and you can just `stat()` them directly.

**UPDATE**: Just to clarify, this is *not* the same thing as calling `chroot()`, it's just an ordinary change of the process' current directory.

Comment: Nice workaround, but is there no way without **chdir**? **UPDATE:** chdir I meant instead of chroot!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, if after calling `fchdir()` he calls `getcwd()`, would he get the _real_ name of the directory?

Comment: @rodrigo: Yes, it returns the path where `DIR *` is pointing to!

Answer (score 1):

Based on @unwind answer, and since you are in linux:

- Call `dirfd()` to get the file descriptor of the directory
- Get your pid using `getpid()`
- Read the link `/proc/<pid>/fd/<dirfd>` using `readlink()`. It will refer to your directory by name!

Comment: Nice way, it seems better than `fchdir`!
But these answers mean that there is no straight way of doing it, right?

Comment: @PLuS. Right. Generally speaking, you cannot go from a file-descriptor to a file-name. That's by design of the unix file system: `file-name -> dir-entry -> inode <- open-file-description <- file-descriptor` (well, maybe not too exact, but you get the idea...). The /proc readlink method is just a linux hack to get to this information, which _may_ be accurate.